# Azure Data Factory import multiple valued lookup fields

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, sharepoint-list, multiple-value, lookupfield

I need to import data from Sharepoint online list using Azure Data Factory in SQL Azure DB.
The share point online list contained a fields of Lookup type, with options "Allow Multiple Values" ON.

I use Azure Data Factory as tool to copy data from SP to Azure SQL DB.
If field is a normal lookup field, i have no problem and i import his value.
If field is a lookup field with options "Allow Multiple Values" ON, i have problem and i don't see the field in mapping, so i can't import.
I search in documentation but i don't find nothing to highlight this case.

Is there a way to import SP lookup field with options "Allow Multiple Values" ON with Azure Data Factory?

Thanks a lot,
p.

Comment: Can you show us any screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

The fields with “Allow Multiple Values” will be treated as complex type which are not supported currently.

We would suggest you to add the feedback in [Azure data factory user voice forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory). All the feedback shared in this forum will be monitored and reviewed by Azure data factory Microsoft engineering team.

Once you have added the feedback , please share that here , so that other community members can up-vote and/or comment on that